# Is their a way to create singe object of an intent on a button click

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin.android, singleton

I am creating an android application in Xamarin android, I have placed the navigations button on the button and they are fixed as in the image.
[image: home screen with navigation buttons] Is there a way to open an intent on those button clicks and if it is clicked again then that same intent is opened and no new intent is created, like if I were to open the notification tab, I would write this code on notification icon click

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,typeof(notification));
this.StartActivity(intent);
```

but it will create a new intent every time on button click, I want a single intent object to be displayed every time when button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

`Intent` is mostly used to start an `activity` so as long as your activity is still running, you can just use this:

```
startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);
```

In your case, it looks like the activity your intent is associated with is to open the "notification tab". And I assume that that activity is destroyed whenever you switch to other tabs. So the question becomes whether you can preserve the same activity instead of creating one or more intent. Because as long as your activity is still running, you can just use `startActivityIfNeed` with the same intent.